# Cannot install IBM Mobile First Platform Studio 7.1.0 in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

Java EE IDE for Web Developers. 
Version: Mars.1 Service Release  (4.5.1)

java version "1.8.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)

I tried to install IBM Mobile First Platform Studio 7.1.0 from Eclipse Marketplace, but I got this error:

The following solutions are not available: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0 (id=com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group, com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group, com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group, site=http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mfpsupdate/)

Comment: Hi @Dony I am experiencing this issue as well. I am contacting development about it now and will get back to you once I receive a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem causing this has been identified and should hopefully be resolved soon (the plug-in is to be re-uploaded to the Eclipse Marketplace).

Solution: check again in a few hours.

Comment: Hi @Idan Adar, currently am not getting version 7.1 from eclipse market , please help me to install 7.1 version as am working on MF7.1

Comment: download the Eclipse installatio zip for MFP 7.1 from: http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/#past-releases